# Win Server 2k and Win 7 client

Tags: windows-server-2000

I have a Win Server 2000 system with AD configured.  The network consists of an OKI printer, a network server, a wifi router a Win 2k client and the server.  I'm trying to connect a Win 7 client.  The purpose of the network, besides sharing equipment is to move files from client to client and scatter backups over more than 1 machine.

The Win 7 client is configured for DHCP and does in fact receive it's IP and DNS configuration from the server and it sees the printer, wifi router and network drive, but does not see the Win 2k client nor the Win 2k server.

I have tried the LAN Management Authentication Level set to 'Send LM & NTLM responses' with the 128 bit encryption removed.  I've also done the registry hack on the key 'LmCompatibilityLevel'.

Neither of these have helped.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a fix or is Win 2k totally incompatible?
2. Is the best (or quickest/cheapest) fix to upgrade the server to Win 2k3 and not worry about the Win 2k client?

Thanks for any help.

Ray Kruse
Buffalo, KY

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either of those things have any bearing on seeing the other machines on the network. Is the Win7 computer joined to the domain? Is network discovery turned on on the Win7 computer? If the Win7 computer is not joined to the domain, is it's workgroup name the same as the domain name? I would check these things first before modifying the authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows 7 on the same domain as the other computers?  I'm not sure 'unable to find AD DC' is a real error message, what was it?  When you say it got DHCP, did you validate that the DNS entries it got allowed it to find the DC? Can you ping the DC name from the Windows 7 PC? If not, can you ping the long name for the DC (hostname.domainname)?  If not, what DNS servers is the Win7 computer looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The Win7 machine is on the same network as everything else (very small system, only one network), but I can not configure it to join a domain.  The message 'unable to find AD DC' I took to mean 'active directory domain controller'.

The Win7 machine is configured to get IP and DNS info through DHCP, and the IP address it configured with (verified by IPCONFIG) was a valid one.  It also showed up on the server/domain controller in the DHCP/computers area.  I didn't check the DNS address, but would assume that it was correct since the DHCP transaction went through for IP.  I can ping the server IP address but haven't tried to ping the DC name.

The system consists of only one server which handles the file sharing and the domain controller functions.  As I said previously, the Win7 machine can see everything on the network except the Win2k machines (one server, one client).

I can also get out through the satellite router to the Internet, so, again, it seems to show that the DHCP address configuration is correct.

Ray

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows 7 do you have? You need Pro, Enterprise or Ultimate.
Can you ping the DC by name? NetBIOS name or FQDN?
In the TCP/IP properties is there a WINS entry for the Win7 PC?
While there, do you have the DNS Suffix for your domain listed?
When you try to add the Win7 PC to the domain, do you enter the NetBIOS domain name or the FQDN? try both. Can you post a screen capture of the error you get when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.  I found a solution a couple of weeks ago, but have lost my notes from it so I can't provide the exact details.  It involved creating a Win2000 emulation entry in the registry.  That allowed all the Win2k nodes to show up on the Win7 discovery.